# Function re.sub() refuses to work when I change an ANSI string to UNICODE one

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I use ANSI characters it works as expected:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = ur'(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\?'
>>> s = 'what is it?'
>>> re.sub(r, ur'\1<br>\2<br>\3<br>', s, re.UNICODE)
u'what<br>is<br>it<br>'
```

But when I change the string `s` to a similar one but contains of unicode characters - it doesn't work as I want:

```
>>> s = u'что это есть?'
>>> re.sub(r, ur'\1<br>\2<br>\3<br>', s, re.UNICODE)
u'\u0427\u0442\u043e \u044d\u0442\u043e \u0435\u0441\u0442\u044c?'
```

It looks strange (the string stays unchanged) because I use `re.UNICODE` in the both cases... However `re.match` successfully matches the groups with a `UNICODE` flag:

```
>>> m = re.match(r, s, re.UNICODE)
>>> m.group(1)
u'\u0447\u0442\u043e'
>>> m.group(2)
u'\u044d\u0442\u043e'
>>> m.group(3)
u'\u0435\u0441\u0442\u044c'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify `re.UNICODE` as `flags` parameter

```
re.sub(r, ur'\1<br>\2<br>\3<br>', s, flags = re.UNICODE)
```

Otherwise Python correctly assumes that the 4th parameter is `count`, as specified in the [re documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Full Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
r = ur'(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\?'
#s = 'what is it?'
s = u'что это есть?'
print re.sub(r, ur'\1<br>\2<br>\3<br>', s, flags = re.UNICODE).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I passed it to another parameter. Thank you very much!